# asp.net doesnt display web page when connected to internet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a website in asp.net when I disable my internet connection it runs but otherwise when I am connected to the internet I get this error:

> ERROR
>   The requested URL could not be
>   retrieved
>
> ---
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://localhost:4719/IWS/
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed  The
>   system returned:
>
> (111) Connection refusedThe remote host or network may be down. Please
>   try the request again.
>
> Your cache administrator is root.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to go through a proxy? If so, disable it for local addresses.